# xcode and run scripts

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, xcode4

I have a separate target to run a script and when I run the script it gives me an exit code 2. Based on the documentation [here](http://gentlebytes.com/appledoc-docs-examples-xcode/) at the bottom, I can see that the error is logged, but where can I see it? I need to know more than just the exit code

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to look at the shell script and determine what is throwing exit code 2.

If there is more than one exit code 2 in your shell script, you should make it so each error throws a unique error code. It is kind of the whole point of error codes..

Comment: the exit code 2 means that there is an error. That's what it says on the docs, nothing more

Comment: Right. But if it is a shell script you can edit it in a text editor and put in unique exit codes if needed. Otherwise if there is only one exit 2 in the script you will know what is causing the error.